# Monitor access to azure devops git repo

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is there anyway to monitor access to a git repository?

We currently restrict access so only devs with permission can download our code, but we'd like to track the IP addresses from where the repo has been accessed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can restrict access so that only people within your corporate network can access your Azure DevOps account by using [Azure Active Directory conditional access](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2017/07/27/limit-access-to-just-visual-studio-team-services-using-azure-active-directory-premium/).

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for responding!